# question quality and resulting answers

Tags: discussion

So SO encourages/demands/desires us to write complete questions, with lots of details, I suppose debugging information, and anything else that would help solve the problem.

But in my experience, complete questions don't get answered. I've had many questions where I explained thoroughly my problem, gave debugging information, thinking that would attract more answers. But oh how I was wrong.

Many times I have changed a question from:

> I have this problem, here is my setup: x, y, z. Here is the debugging output: qqqqqqq:qq
>   Here is some other vital info that can easily be used by knowledgeable people to solve my issue.

To:

> Why doesnt this work? I tried and tried but I have no idea whats wrong.

Guess which one got answered. If you guessed the second one, you are right.

I am just trying to see if this is generalized behaviour or just something that has happened to me. I don't have enough data to support a claim that "this always happens", but it has happened to me more than once, quite consistently.

*****Maybe because people don't like to engage in a question that seems complicated? So a "simpler/noobier" question serves like a "bait".

Comment: Links to examples would help. Also, since you seem to be a Magento user, you might be interested in taking a look at [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have deleted most unanswered questions. So maybe I shouldnt be asking this right now, with no "evidence". I was just wondering. But good to know about the magento SO, thanks.

Comment: Well, it's generally true that trivial questions tend to attract more answers, as they are accessible to a wider audience (see: [Parkinson's law of triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality)).

Comment: @localhost tread very carefully deleting questions. Deleting a question is behaviour that can lead to a question ban. Whether you delete because you're embarrassed of it, it worked and you got your answers, or you just think it's pointless because it didn't get an answer, you are following a risky path by deleting ANY of your questions.