# Best close reason for find-error-in-my-lengthy-code questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

When reviewing questions, I often meet that pattern:

The question has short description what the OP wanted to achieve, a **very large block of code** and the summary that this is not functioning (no error, just it's not doing that what OP had expected).

While some of them can be valid questions, when the code is behaving other as expected or doing nothing because of bug, undocumented feature or bad documentation, usually in those cases the OP is able to identify crucial block, and the large block may come at the end as context.

When there's only a large block of code, this is like saying "Find error in my code". It's a symptom that someone posted his code to the internet because it was for him faster as debugging it himself. He didn't even make effort to identify the place in code that is probably the source of problem. So it deserves to be described as **not constructive**.

On the other side, it's not a typical write-it-for-me pattern. The OP may have analysed that code for long, though without effort, and now is posting it here. But usually the error is trivial - misspelling or wrong line of code. It's very improbable that someone else will made similar error and will find it here. So it should be closed as **too localized**.

My questions is, which of those 2 closing reasons fits better for that group of questions?

Comment: What you describe sounds more like NARQ to me than NC or TL.

Comment: They are RQ since the question is quite clear: I want X and I've done Y but I have Z, how to change Y to Y' so that Z would become X...

Comment: Too localized comes to mind, its my go-to in situations like this.

Comment: Too localized is appropriate, if it's deep in a load of code and the description isn't going to reliably lead you to the problem. If, however, this same problem is likely to come up for someone else who has the same error message, and the error message is highlighted clearly, leave it open for googlers to find.

Comment: NARQ: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." If a question has a big block of code and doesn't tell us _exactly_ what the problem is, I'd say it's both vague and incomplete.

Comment: There's a difference between "this problem wasn't very deep or interesting for me" and "it's unlikely to ever help anyone else". Don't close for the first reason. Remember SO is based on the long tail.

Comment: @AndrewC well, the questions with error message are the other class. I've described those that give no error (OP has not included it OR everything is 'functioning', but for example returning from loop too soon)

Comment: @ŁukaszLech OK, but please don't let's start closing all coding problem questions. Here's the current set of closing hoops you have to jump through: If you don't post your code, it's NARQ. If your code is too slimmed down you haven't given enough context. TL => DR. If your code doesn't compile you haven't made enough effort to solve your problem. If your code compiles it's too localized. I worry that there's no sanctioned route through this. I don't think we need a vague guideline saying that if the code's broken we use a particular close reason.

Comment: See possible unintended consequences of having this as a general, broad rule in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180806/question-quality-and-resulting-answers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Too localized. If the error is caused by a missing semicolon (or some other syntax error), or simply because the OP didn't read or understand how to use a language feature, that's **not** a question that's likely to help anyone in the future.  Likewise, if they just find it easier to dump their code on the internets than to debug it themselves, that only serves one person, the OP.

Comment: I love that answer. You've shown me how to convert that what I've considered not constructive to too localized, getting rid of the dilemma :)

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Also, less likely you'll get declined flags.  (Not speaking to you personally, since I don't know your flag history) I've seen a lot of users lately flag something 'not constructive' and I've had to decline it (even though I ended up taking action on the question).  Bill's answer is spot on - if it's not ever going to help anyone else, it's too localized.